# NSFileHandle readInBackgroundAndNotify and NSMenu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using `NSFileHandle readInBackgroundAndNotify` to read data from pipe. But until application system status bar menu is opened I don't receive `NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification` notification. If menu is collapsed everything works fine.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Everything started working as it should after changing NSFileHandle call

from:

`[handle readInBackgroundAndNotify]`

to:

`[handle readInBackgroundAndNotifyForModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes]]`